# Unable to use currency Pound in the package to-words in react

Tags: reactjs, currency

I have a requirement where I need to convert number to words for which I am using this package in react => https://www.npmjs.com/package/to-words

But unable to use for currency Pound

```
const toWords = new ToWords({
         localeCode: 'en-GB',
        // converterOptions: {
        //    currency: false,
        //   ignoreDecimal: false,
        //   ignoreZeroCurrency: false,
        // }
      });

    dueAmountDataWords = toWords.convert(120000);
```

I need guidance on how to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll down to the page you can see. It only supports these locales:

Supported Locale: **en-IN**, **en-MU**, **en-US** and **fa-IR**.

It has limitations for the locale you want to use. [Here you can see](https://www.npmjs.com/package/to-words#options):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I need a wayout to use en-GB so that I can get the currency pound in converted number to word output, please guide how I can do that

Comment: They have included one inspiration link from SO [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/to-words#inspiration-for-core-logic).